# Definition 11.4 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about Rudin's definition of interval

> **Definition**
>
> Let $\mathbb R^{p}$ denote the $p$-dimensional Euclidean space.By an interval in $\mathbb R^{p}$ we mean the set of points $x=(x_{1},\dots ,x_{p})$ such that $$a_{i}\leq x_{i} \leq b_{i} \tag 1$$ or the set of points which is characterized by (1) with any or all of the $\leq$ be replaced by $<$

My question is, does this include the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Comment: They forgot to specify the set from where the values for $a_i,b_i$ are taken. They should have done it. Those unbounded intervals are useful. So, it could be useful to allow them in the definition. A glance to a handful of the theorems and definitions that follow it doesn't seem to matter if you include them or not.

Comment: I believe Rudin stated earlier on that page that $a_i,b_i$ are members of the extended reals.

Comment: In the definition of $m(I)$ that follows one would need to allow the value $+\infty$ for the $I$ that are unbounded and all sides are either unbounded or bounded but not a single point, if you allow the unbounded intervals. In other words, in the product that defines $m$ one could define $0\cdot \infty=0$, $+\infty\cdot a=+\infty$ for $a$ real, $+\infty-a=+\infty$ for $a$ real, $a-(-\infty)=+\infty$ for $a$ real, $+\infty-(-\infty)=+\infty$, ... I guess one can save some words by not including them.

Comment: Which Rudin book are you using?